# Can't boot any OS from BIOS or UEFI after installing Fedora

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, fedora

(Running on [Asus TaiChi](http://www.asus.com/vivo/en/taichi.htm))

When I try to boot without USB, I get sent straight to setup screen. If I press <kbd>esc</kbd> prior to setup screen, I enter the `Please select boot device` boot dialog. However, my only option in the boot dialog is `Enter Setup`. I have tried all variations of enabling and disabling `Secure Boot`, `Fast Boot` and `CSM` but to no avail.

Although I am still able to boot via USB (currently in Lubuntu), I have lost all capacity to boot into any other OS. Initially I thought I may have wiped the whole hard drive but GParted (screenshot link below) shows this is not the case.

How do I get my old boot back? (I want to keep Windows 8. Data is not important from any OSs since it is all backed up)

I believe I would have to delete the Fedora partition, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Here is a screenshot GParted from Lubuntu.

[image]

Fedora has a lock, so I'm not sure how I could delete this partition. Note it's strange how the Fedora partition occupies all 19.53GB since all I have done is install Fedora.. Right-clicking for more information on GParted shows `Status: Fedora active`.

Below are the results of Boot-Repair Boot Info Script.

```
              Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 
    191873024 of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this 
    location and looks in partition 99 for .
 => Syslinux MBR (3.61-4.03) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.
 => Windows is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda8: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda8,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so


sda9: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda10: _________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda11: _________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       BIOS Boot partition
    Boot sector type:  Grub2's core.img
    Boot sector info: 

sda12: _________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /grub2/grub.cfg

sda13: _________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       LVM2_member
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 4.03 2010-10-22
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 8132480 of /dev/sdb1 for its 
                       second stage. SYSLINUX is installed in the / 
                       directory. The integrity check of the ADV area failed. 
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /syslinux.cfg /ldlinux.sys

sdc1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

fedora-swap': __________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda8,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

mount: unknown filesystem type ''

fedora-root': __________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda8,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 256.1 GB, 256060514304 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 31130 cylinders, total 500118192 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *              1   500,118,191   500,118,191  ee GPT


GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sda1           2,048       616,447       614,400 EFI System partition
/dev/sda2         616,448     2,459,647     1,843,200 Windows Recovery Environment (Windows)
/dev/sda3       2,459,648     2,721,791       262,144 Microsoft Reserved Partition (Windows)
/dev/sda4       2,721,792   182,288,383   179,566,592 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sda5     202,768,384   243,978,239    41,209,856 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sda6     449,765,376   458,153,983     8,388,608 -
/dev/sda7     458,153,984   500,117,503    41,963,520 Windows Recovery Environment (Windows)
/dev/sda8     243,978,240   400,650,239   156,672,000 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sda9     441,610,240   449,765,375     8,155,136 Swap partition (Linux)
/dev/sda10    182,288,384   191,873,023     9,584,640 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sda11    191,873,024   191,875,071         2,048 BIOS Boot partition
/dev/sda12    191,875,072   192,899,071     1,024,000 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sda13    400,650,240   441,610,239    40,960,000 Logical Volume Manager (LVM) partition (Linux)

Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sdb: 7784 MB, 7784628224 bytes
88 heads, 24 sectors/track, 7199 cylinders, total 15204352 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1    *          3,160    15,204,351    15,201,192   c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


Drive: sdc _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sdc: 512 MB, 512753664 bytes
16 heads, 32 sectors/track, 1956 cylinders, total 1001472 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdc1    *             32     1,001,471     1,001,440   e W95 FAT16 (LBA)


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/mapper/fedora-root 3f7df13c-d8bd-4864-9198-6c3ebe5dd25c   ext4       
/dev/mapper/fedora-swap f531d567-dd64-4e9d-9d8e-a96dcf79ca20   swap       
/dev/sda1        A067-306C                              vfat       SYSTEM
/dev/sda10       08ba6d95-4b2e-46cb-b992-e3aa2cdd3273   ext4       First 5GB
/dev/sda12       319a3ec4-6b3e-465a-93ef-3ccc20d8d6bc   ext4       
/dev/sda13       y1sx97-qMgd-spd4-9mEz-FXQ0-pbZg-MOfaam LVM2_member 
/dev/sda2        885202085201FC26                       ntfs       Recovery
/dev/sda4        A478065E7806301A                       ntfs       OS
/dev/sda5        BAFCB10EFCB0C643                       ntfs       DATA
/dev/sda7        FAC20D83C20D44FB                       ntfs       Restore
/dev/sda8        31054370-281d-4357-b89d-1d710ded409a   ext4       
/dev/sda9        1ebb0d28-2b27-4ba5-afa5-fac343a9c52b   swap       
/dev/sdb1        3433-3231                              vfat       KINGSTON
/dev/sdc1        AFD5-FC17                              vfat       disgo

========================= "ls -R /dev/mapper/" output: =========================

/dev/mapper:
control
fedora-root
fedora-swap

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/loop0       /rofs                    squashfs   (ro,noatime)
/dev/mapper/fedora-root /media/lubuntu/3f7df13c-d8bd-4864-9198-6c3ebe5dd25c ext4       (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sda10       /media/lubuntu/First 5GB ext4       (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sda12       /media/lubuntu/319a3ec4-6b3e-465a-93ef-3ccc20d8d6bc ext4       (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sda2        /media/lubuntu/Recovery  fuseblk    (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda4        /media/lubuntu/OS        fuseblk    (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda5        /media/lubuntu/DATA      fuseblk    (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda7        /media/lubuntu/Restore   fuseblk    (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sdb1        /cdrom                   vfat       (ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sdc1        /media/lubuntu/disgo     vfat       (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=999,gid=999,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks2)


============================ sda12/grub2/grub.cfg: =============================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub2-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  load_env
fi
set default="${saved_entry}"

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod lvm
insmod ext2
set root='lvm/fedora-root'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='lvm/fedora-root'  3f7df13c-d8bd-4864-9198-6c3ebe5dd25c
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 3f7df13c-d8bd-4864-9198-6c3ebe5dd25c
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_GB
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt12'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt12 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt12 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt12 --hint='hd0,gpt12'  319a3ec4-6b3e-465a-93ef-3ccc20d8d6bc
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 319a3ec4-6b3e-465a-93ef-3ccc20d8d6bc
fi
insmod gfxmenu
loadfont ($root)/grub2/themes/system/DejaVuSans-10.pf2
loadfont ($root)/grub2/themes/system/DejaVuSans-12.pf2
loadfont ($root)/grub2/themes/system/DejaVuSans-Bold-14.pf2
loadfont ($root)/grub2/fonts/unicode.pf2
insmod png
set theme=($root)/grub2/themes/system/theme.txt
export theme
set timeout=5
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
menuentry 'Fedora' --class fedora --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-3f7df13c-d8bd-4864-9198-6c3ebe5dd25c' {
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt12'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt12 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt12 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt12 --hint='hd0,gpt12'  319a3ec4-6b3e-465a-93ef-3ccc20d8d6bc
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 319a3ec4-6b3e-465a-93ef-3ccc20d8d6bc
    fi
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.6.10-4.fc18.x86_64 ...'
    linux   /vmlinuz-3.6.10-4.fc18.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/fedora-root ro rd.lvm.lv=fedora/swap rd.md=0 rd.dm=0  rd.luks=0 rd.lvm.lv=fedora/root vconsole.keymap=uk rhgb quiet 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /initramfs-3.6.10-4.fc18.x86_64.img
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Fedora' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-3f7df13c-d8bd-4864-9198-6c3ebe5dd25c' {
    menuentry 'Fedora, with Linux 3.6.10-4.fc18.x86_64' --class fedora --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.6.10-4.fc18.x86_64-advanced-3f7df13c-d8bd-4864-9198-6c3ebe5dd25c' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt12'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt12 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt12 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt12 --hint='hd0,gpt12'  319a3ec4-6b3e-465a-93ef-3ccc20d8d6bc
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 319a3ec4-6b3e-465a-93ef-3ccc20d8d6bc
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.6.10-4.fc18.x86_64 ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-3.6.10-4.fc18.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/fedora-root ro rd.lvm.lv=fedora/swap rd.md=0 rd.dm=0  rd.luks=0 rd.lvm.lv=fedora/root vconsole.keymap=uk rhgb quiet 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initramfs-3.6.10-4.fc18.x86_64.img
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_ppc_terminfo ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_ppc_terminfo ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows Recovery Environment (loader) (on /dev/sda2)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-885202085201FC26' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,gpt2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2 --hint='hd0,gpt2'  885202085201FC26
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 885202085201FC26
    fi
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
menuentry 'Windows 8 (loader) (on /dev/sda4)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-A478065E7806301A' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,gpt4'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt4 --hint='hd0,gpt4'  A478065E7806301A
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root A478065E7806301A
    fi
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda12: Location of files loaded by Grub: ===================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

               =                grub2/grub.cfg                                 1
               =                initramfs-3.6.10-4.fc18.x86_64.img             5
               =                initrd-plymouth.img                            1
               =                vmlinuz-3.6.10-4.fc18.x86_64                   1

============================== sdb1/syslinux.cfg: ==============================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
default menu.c32
prompt 0
menu title UNetbootin
timeout 100

label unetbootindefault
menu label Default
kernel /ubnkern
append initrd=/ubninit file=/cdrom/preseed/lubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash --

label ubnentry0
menu label ^Help
kernel /ubnkern
append initrd=/ubninit 

label ubnentry1
menu label ^Try Lubuntu without installing
kernel /casper/vmlinuz
append initrd=/casper/initrd.lz file=/cdrom/preseed/lubuntu.seed boot=casper  quiet splash --

label ubnentry2
menu label ^Install Lubuntu
kernel /casper/vmlinuz
append initrd=/casper/initrd.lz file=/cdrom/preseed/lubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity  quiet splash --

label ubnentry3
menu label ^Check disc for defects
kernel /casper/vmlinuz
append initrd=/casper/initrd.lz boot=casper integrity-check  quiet splash --

label ubnentry4
menu label Test ^memory
kernel /install/mt86plus
append initrd=/ubninit 

label ubnentry5
menu label ^Boot from first hard disk
kernel /ubnkern
append initrd=/ubninit 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

================= sdb1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux: ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

            ?? = ??             ldlinux.sys                                    1
            ?? = ??             menu.c32                                       1
            ?? = ??             syslinux.cfg                                   1

============== sdb1: Version of COM32(R) files used by Syslinux: ===============

 menu.c32                           :  COM32R module (v4.xx)

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc: ========================

Unknown GPT Partiton Type
dee2bfd3af3ddf11ba40e3a556d89593
Unknown BootLoader on sda1

00000000  eb 58 90 4d 53 44 4f 53  35 2e 30 00 02 08 5e 1b  |.X.MSDOS5.0...^.|
00000010  02 00 00 00 00 f8 00 00  3f 00 ff 00 00 08 00 00  |........?.......|
00000020  00 60 09 00 51 02 00 00  00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  |.`..Q...........|
00000030  01 00 06 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  80 00 29 6c 30 67 a0 4e  4f 20 4e 41 4d 45 20 20  |..)l0g.NO NAME  |
00000050  20 20 46 41 54 33 32 20  20 20 33 c9 8e d1 bc f4  |  FAT32   3.....|
00000060  7b 8e c1 8e d9 bd 00 7c  88 56 40 88 4e 02 8a 56  |{......|.V@.N..V|
00000070  40 b4 41 bb aa 55 cd 13  72 10 81 fb 55 aa 75 0a  |@.A..U..r...U.u.|
00000080  f6 c1 01 74 05 fe 46 02  eb 2d 8a 56 40 b4 08 cd  |...t..F..-.V@...|
00000090  13 73 05 b9 ff ff 8a f1  66 0f b6 c6 40 66 0f b6  |.s......f...@f..|
000000a0  d1 80 e2 3f f7 e2 86 cd  c0 ed 06 41 66 0f b7 c9  |...?.......Af...|
000000b0  66 f7 e1 66 89 46 f8 83  7e 16 00 75 39 83 7e 2a  |f..f.F..~..u9.~*|
000000c0  00 77 33 66 8b 46 1c 66  83 c0 0c bb 00 80 b9 01  |.w3f.F.f........|
000000d0  00 e8 2c 00 e9 a8 03 a1  f8 7d 80 c4 7c 8b f0 ac  |..,......}..|...|
000000e0  84 c0 74 17 3c ff 74 09  b4 0e bb 07 00 cd 10 eb  |..t.<.t.........|
000000f0  ee a1 fa 7d eb e4 a1 7d  80 eb df 98 cd 16 cd 19  |...}...}........|
00000100  66 60 80 7e 02 00 0f 84  20 00 66 6a 00 66 50 06  |f`.~.... .fj.fP.|
00000110  53 66 68 10 00 01 00 b4  42 8a 56 40 8b f4 cd 13  |Sfh.....B.V@....|
00000120  66 58 66 58 66 58 66 58  eb 33 66 3b 46 f8 72 03  |fXfXfXfX.3f;F.r.|
00000130  f9 eb 2a 66 33 d2 66 0f  b7 4e 18 66 f7 f1 fe c2  |..*f3.f..N.f....|
00000140  8a ca 66 8b d0 66 c1 ea  10 f7 76 1a 86 d6 8a 56  |..f..f....v....V|
00000150  40 8a e8 c0 e4 06 0a cc  b8 01 02 cd 13 66 61 0f  |@............fa.|
00000160  82 74 ff 81 c3 00 02 66  40 49 75 94 c3 42 4f 4f  |.t.....f@Iu..BOO|
00000170  54 4d 47 52 20 20 20 20  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |TMGR    ........|
00000180  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 0d 0a 44 69  |..............Di|
000001b0  73 6b 20 65 72 72 6f 72  ff 0d 0a 50 72 65 73 73  |sk error...Press|
000001c0  20 61 6e 79 20 6b 65 79  20 74 6f 20 72 65 73 74  | any key to rest|
000001d0  61 72 74 0d 0a 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |art.............|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ac 01 b9 01 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200

Unknown BootLoader on sdc1

00000000  eb 3c 90 44 4f 4b 30 31  2e 30 32 00 02 20 01 00  |.<.DOK01.02.. ..|
00000010  02 00 02 00 00 f8 7b 00  20 00 10 00 20 00 00 00  |......{. ... ...|
00000020  e0 47 0f 00 80 00 29 17  fc d5 af 64 69 73 67 6f  |.G....)....disgo|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 46 41  54 31 36 20 20 20 33 c9  |......FAT16   3.|
00000040  8e d1 bc fc 7b 16 07 bd  78 00 c5 76 00 1e 56 16  |....{...x..v..V.|
00000050  55 bf 22 05 89 7e 00 89  4e 02 b1 0b fc f3 a4 06  |U."..~..N.......|
00000060  1f bd 00 7c c6 45 fe 0f  38 4e 24 7d 20 8b c1 99  |...|.E..8N$} ...|
00000070  e8 7e 01 83 eb 3a 66 a1  1c 7c 66 3b 07 8a 57 fc  |.~...:f..|f;..W.|
00000080  75 06 80 ca 02 88 56 02  80 c3 10 73 ed 33 c9 fe  |u.....V....s.3..|
00000090  06 d8 7d 8a 46 10 98 f7  66 16 03 46 1c 13 56 1e  |..}.F...f..F..V.|
000000a0  03 46 0e 13 d1 8b 76 11  60 89 46 fc 89 56 fe b8  |.F....v.`.F..V..|
000000b0  20 00 f7 e6 8b 5e 0b 03  c3 48 f7 f3 01 46 fc 11  | ....^...H...F..|
000000c0  4e fe 61 bf 00 07 e8 28  01 72 3e 38 2d 74 17 60  |N.a....(.r>8-t.`|
000000d0  b1 0b be d8 7d f3 a6 61  74 3d 4e 74 09 83 c7 20  |....}..at=Nt... |
000000e0  3b fb 72 e7 eb dd fe 0e  d8 7d 7b a7 be 7f 7d ac  |;.r......}{...}.|
000000f0  98 03 f0 ac 98 40 74 0c  48 74 13 b4 0e bb 07 00  |.....@t.Ht......|
00000100  cd 10 eb ef be 82 7d eb  e6 be 80 7d eb e1 cd 16  |......}....}....|
00000110  5e 1f 66 8f 04 cd 19 be  81 7d 8b 7d 1a 8d 45 fe  |^.f......}.}..E.|
00000120  8a 4e 0d f7 e1 03 46 fc  13 56 fe b1 04 e8 c2 00  |.N....F..V......|
00000130  72 d7 ea 00 02 70 00 52  50 06 53 6a 01 6a 10 91  |r....p.RP.Sj.j..|
00000140  8b 46 18 a2 26 05 96 92  33 d2 f7 f6 91 f7 f6 42  |.F..&...3......B|
00000150  87 ca f7 76 1a 8a f2 8a  e8 c0 cc 02 0a cc b8 01  |...v............|
00000160  02 80 7e 02 0e 75 04 b4  42 8b f4 8a 56 24 cd 13  |..~..u..B...V$..|
00000170  61 61 72 0a 40 75 01 42  03 5e 0b 49 75 77 c3 03  |aar.@u.B.^.Iuw..|
00000180  18 01 27 0d 0a 49 6e 76  61 6c 69 64 20 73 79 73  |..'..Invalid sys|
00000190  74 65 6d 20 64 69 73 6b  ff 0d 0a 44 69 73 6b 20  |tem disk...Disk |
000001a0  49 2f 4f 20 65 72 72 6f  72 ff 0d 0a 52 65 70 6c  |I/O error...Repl|
000001b0  61 63 65 20 74 68 65 20  64 69 73 6b 2c 20 61 6e  |ace the disk, an|
000001c0  64 20 74 68 65 6e 20 70  72 65 73 73 20 61 6e 79  |d then press any|
000001d0  20 6b 65 79 0d 0a 00 00  49 4f 20 20 20 20 20 20  | key....IO      |
000001e0  53 59 53 4d 53 44 4f 53  20 20 20 53 59 53 7f 01  |SYSMSDOS   SYS..|
000001f0  00 41 bb 00 07 60 66 6a  00 e9 3b ff 00 00 55 aa  |.A...`fj..;...U.|
00000200

Unknown BootLoader on fedora-swap'


Unknown BootLoader on fedora-root'



=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
./bootinfoscript: line 1646: [: 2.73495e+09: integer expression expected
  One or more specified logical volume(s) not found.
  One or more specified logical volume(s) not found.
  One or more specified logical volume(s) not found.
hexdump: /dev/mapper/fedora-swap': No such file or directory
hexdump: /dev/mapper/fedora-swap': No such file or directory
  One or more specified logical volume(s) not found.
  One or more specified logical volume(s) not found.
  One or more specified logical volume(s) not found.
hexdump: /dev/mapper/fedora-root': No such file or directory
hexdump: /dev/mapper/fedora-root': No such file or directory
```

Comment: You don't need to delete Fedora to fix this problem.

Comment: More information is required: First, a description of what happens when you try to boot without your USB drive -- for instance, do you get a message to the effect that no boot loaders were found, does GRUB come up and give you a `grub>` prompt, does GRUB come up but fail to launch any options, etc.? Second, run [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) and post a link to the RESULTS.txt file that it produces.

Answer (score 2):

You've got what must be an EFI-mode installation of Windows on your hard disk, but something seems to have wiped the Windows boot loader from the [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition). OTOH, you *do* have a fallback boot loader on the ESP, and what looks like a backup of that boot loader created by Ubuntu's Boot Repair tool. If I'm reading the clues right, *something* should boot from the ESP -- probably GRUB. OTOH, that's clearly not happening.

As a first step, I recommend you go into your firmware and disable Secure Boot. The details of how to do this vary from one computer to another, so I can't give precise directions; you'll just have to dig into the firmware settings to see what you can find. It's conceivable that GRUB will start up at this point, but I don't know if it will do anything useful.

If GRUB doesn't start or if it doesn't do anything useful, I recommend you run Ubuntu's Boot Repair tool again, but select the Advanced options and check the "Restore EFI Backups" option. (See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/bootrepair.html) for more details on how to do this.) With any luck, that will restore Windows to bootability, but nothing else will boot. If Windows still doesn't boot at this point, track down a Windows emergency recovery disc and use it to restore Windows to bootability.

Where you proceed from here is up to you. If you believe your Linux installation is basically sound, you can try installing an [EFI-mode boot loader for Linux.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) You can do this from Windows or from a Linux emergency disk, or even from Linux on your hard disk if you can get it to boot. The details will vary depending on what you can get booted and what boot loader you decide to use.